# How to add content to an SVN directory without checking out its contents?

Tags: svn

Today I needed to add two Android projects to our Subversion repository but I had a problem.
The directory in the repository already contained a lot of projects and I didn't want to checkout all of them.
Is it possible add two directories to that directory without checking out everything?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply `import` the new stuff right into the repository without any working copy:

```
svn import INSTALL.txt $SVN_REPO/trunk/proj1/INSTALL.txt
```

Works with directories (aka. "projects") also.

```
svn import proj2 $SVN_REPO/trunk/proj2
```

After importing you must checkout the stuff in order to continue your work:

```
rm -rf proj2/*
svn co $SVN_REPO/trunk/proj2 proj2
```

Comment: in mac os I used this svn import proj2 $SVN_REPO/trunk/proj2 -m "comment there". Withou -m command it give the error: svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found

Answer (score 20):

You can checkout a directory without getting any of its content thus:

```
svn co --depth empty SVN_URL
```

You can then move your projects into your working copy, then `svn add`, and `svn ci`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's possible to check out only the topmost children of a given directory:

```
svn co --depth immediates REPOSITORY_URL
```

You can then work your way down the tree, checking out another layer at a time

```
cd SUBDIR
svn update --set-depth immediates
```

Or, you can check out an entire tree from one subdirectory

```
cd SUBDIR
svn update --set-depth infinity
```